# Add list item from web part programmaticaly

Tags: list, development, permissions, sandbox-solution

I want to prevent users from accessing a list, but to allow them to use web part programmed in C# to add items to the list.

I tried impersonation and `RunWithElevatedPriviliges` but these are available in farm solutions only. I believe there is a way to solve this without using full trust proxy?

Comment: Only with a Workflow doing the Elevated permission. If a user has right to create an Item, he/she has rights to create an Item <period>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be applied to your scenario, but it may help.

```
$spweb=Get-SPWeb -Identity "<site url>";
$spRoleDefinition = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleDefinition;
$spRoleDefinition.Name = "Submit only";
$spRoleDefinition.Description = "Can submit/add forms/files/items into library or list but cannot view/edit them.";
$spRoleDefinition.BasePermissions = "AddListItems, ViewPages, ViewFormPages, Open";
$spweb.RoleDefinitions.Add($spRoleDefinition);
$spweb.Dispose();
```

From,

[Add Only Permission Level in SharePoint 2010](https://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/add-only-permission-level-in-sharepoint-2010/)